Minimizing the size of the LUKS Header
With cryptsetup I will create some LUKS encrypted files with detached header. In the files I will write once and read repeatedly. I do not need to change any key.
How can the size of the header be kept as small as possible?

You can use the --luks2-metadata-size and --luks2-keyslots-size options for cryptsetup luksFormat to minimize the header.
cryptsetup luksFormat --luks2-metadata-size=16k --luks2-keyslots-size=256k <device>

will give you a 1 MiB LUKS header limited to just one keyslot. You can make this even smaller by telling cryptsetup to not align start of the data area with --align-payload=1 giving you about 300 KiB header. (If you want to use detached header you don't need to use the align-payload option.)
